# Program allows duplicate in set. How it is possoble?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, thread-safety, set

I was checking the synchronizedSet and the normal set with the threads. I wrote the below program.

```
package thread;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * @author Sivaranjani D
 * 
 */

public class ThreadSafeCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SyncList job = new SyncList();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(job);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(job);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(job.set);
        System.out.println("Normal :" + job.set.size());
        System.out.println(job.synSet);
        System.out.println("Synchronized :" + job.synSet.size());
    }
}

class SyncList implements Runnable {
    Set<Integer> synSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Integer>());
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public void run() {
        displaysynchronizedMap();
        displayNormalMap();
    }

    private void displaysynchronizedMap() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            synSet.add(i);
        }
    }

    private void displayNormalMap() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            set.add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

To my surprise, set is allowing duplicates.. How it is possible? Someone please explain this..

Comment: What is the output of your program?  Is the issue that `set` is allowing duplicates, but `synSet` is not?

Comment: yes.. with syncronized set it works perfect. But in the normal set it puts the duplicate values. Output is below,
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 17, 16, 16, 19, 18, 21, 20, 20, 23, 22, 25, 24, 27, 26, 29, 28, 31, 30, 34, 35, 32, 33, 38, 39, 39, 36, 37, 42, 43, 40, 40, 41, 46, 47, 44, 45, 49, 48]
Normal :70
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 16, 19, 18, 21, 20, 23, 22, 25, 24, 27, 26, 29, 28, 31, 30, 34, 35, 32, 33, 38, 39, 36, 37, 42, 43, 40, 41, 46, 47, 44, 45, 49, 48]
Synchronized :50

Answer (score 1):

If you concurrently modify an unsynchronized data structure, *all* bets are off.  You cannot expect that duplicates will be disallowed.  Behavior is completely undefined: for example, [demons may come out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: This is a little suprising for me. Is it expected for a data structure to loose its behaviour in that case? Never saw somewhere mentioned about this :(

Comment: I even got this output for the set: `[24, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
Normal :65`. I mean how is this possible. I clearly see there aren't 65 elements in the set.

Comment: It is totally expected for a data structure to behave that weirdly if it's improperly used in an unsynchronized fashion.

Comment: That is insanely surprising for me. And that is an indication I should really start learning concurrent programming soon.

Answer (score 1):

The HashSet is backed by a HashMap instance. Your two threads call the put() method with the same value and since they run parallel, they both see that the element is not in the Map at the moment. So they go forward, this results in two parallel addEntry() calls (see source of HashMap.java). The same numbers will go into the same bucket by their hashCode, but because the bucket implementation is some form of a linked list, both of your threads will append the numbers to the front of this list.